# Recommend which cross-platform UI framework for C/C++...

Tags: c++, c, user-interface, cross-platform

I am doing an assignment, which require to develop a simple text editor using C/C++. But it is a GUI application, which may port to different platform, for example, windows, linux and mac. Please recommend a ui framework to serve the purpose. Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> [Qt](http://qt.digia.com/product/) is a cross-platform application and UI framework for
>   developers using C++ or QML, a CSS & JavaScript like language.

Quoted from [qt-project.org](http://qt-project.org/)

Comment: +1: even if a simple text editor could probably mean just `#include <QTextEdit>` :-)

Comment: @6502 Yep, throw some menu together for the most important things and you're finished in certainly less than 1k Loc for a rather advanced text editor (which really isn't bad for c++ code). QT is just great +1

Answer (score 1):

The most popular ones I know of are Qt and GTK+.

Answer (score 1):

If you need the most functionality, then [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/products/).

If you need simplicity, then [FLTK](http://www.fltk.org/).

Both run on Windows/OSX/Linux.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend QT. But you can also use wxWidgets.

GTK+ is ok on UNIX based operating systems, but on Windows, is useless.